# Symfony2 custom repository methods

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an entity `League` and `Season` while season has an `@ManyToOne` relationship to league.

now in the `showAction` of my league-controller i want to give an object to the view with all seasons which are belonging to the current ($id) league.

therefor i have implemented a `findAllBelongingSeasons` function in the `LeagueRepository` looking like following:

```
public function findAllBelongingSeasons($league_id)
{
    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('
            SELECT s FROM xxx:Season s
            WHERE s.league_id = :league_id'
        )
        ->setParameter('league_id', $league_id)
        ->getResult();
}
```

The thing is, that i now get the message, that the class season has no field league_id. Shure, in the database at season-table it exists. But doctrine now wanna handle it internaly via objects, and there is no league_id in season, cuz it has an property `$league` with `@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="xxx\xxx\Entity\League")` configured.

so how is it supposed to be done?

appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function findAllBelongingSeasons($league_id)
{
    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('
            SELECT s FROM xxx:Season s
            WHERE s.league = :league_id'
        )
        ->setParameter('league_id', $league_id)
        ->getResult();
}
```

is the correct way (modified `league_id` in `league`)

Basically, as you said, doctrine handle objects that are use like "proxy" to access db tables and columns. In that way you have to referrer to doctirne (objects) mappings and no to db corresponding fields